# vertical scroll then slide through sections

Tags: jquery, css

im in need of some help. im trying to create a slider that is fixed to the top once ive scrolled enough (that bit i get and can do) then it should scroll through 3 sections of content and text. any pointers in how i should do that. here is my mark up.

```
<div class="fixed-slider">
        <section class=" section slider slider-one vertical-align" id="step1">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row is-animated vertical-align">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="indicators">
                            <li class="active"></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                        </ul>
                        <span>Step 1</span>
                        <h2>Download the app on your phone</h2>
                        <p>Download it <span class="selling">Free</span> for your Apple iPhone</p>
                        <a href=""><img src="img/apple-store.svg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="img/step1.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="section slider slider-two vertical-align" id="step2">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row vertical-align is-animated">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="indicators">
                            <li></li>
                            <li class="active"></li>
                            <li></li>
                        </ul>
                        <span>Step 2</span>
                        <h2>Select your style</h2>
                        <p>Choose from a tange of hair and make up styles for any ocassion</p>
                        <a href=""><img src="img/apple-store.svg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="img/step2.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="section slider slider-three vertical-align" id="step3">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row vertical-align is-animated">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="indicators">
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li class="active"></li>
                            <li class="mobile-arrow"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <span>Step 3</span>
                        <h2>Make a Booking</h2>
                        <p>Our easy-to-use booking system allows for quick selection at a time that suits you.</p>
                        <a href=""><img src="img/apple-store.svg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="img/step3.png" alt="">
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        </div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're specifically asking for. Try throwing this up on JSFiddle, and illustrate more clearly what you're looking for.

Comment: Here is the time to start to use capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) with the `scrollOverflow` option as [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).

Then you could use the [scroll Horizontally extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scroll-horizontally.html) to force the horizontal scrolling once you reach the bottom of the first slide.